# Erro ao validar dígito do usuário em jogo da forca

Tags: java

No meu código Java para jogo da forca, surge um erro no momento que testa se o usuário digitou uma das letras da palavra secreta.
erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Código que testa a letra:

```
if (jtChute.getText().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Preencha o campo: 'Chute uma letra' ");
        jtChute.requestFocus();

    } else {
        char[] pal = jlRevela.getText().toUpperCase().toCharArray();
        String armazenada = jlSegredo.getText();

        StringBuilder acertou = new StringBuilder(armazenada); //modifica a string

        char l = jtChute.getText().toUpperCase().charAt(0); //pega a primeira letra

        boolean correto = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < pal.length; i++) { //percorre todas as letras da palavra
            if (pal[i] == l) {
                acertou.setCharAt(i, l);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Parabéns!");

                jlSegredo.setText(armazenada);
                correto = true;
            }
        }
        int vidas = Integer.parseInt(jlResta.getText());
        if (correto == false);
        vidas--;
        jlResta.setText(Integer.toString(vidas));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você errou!");
        if (vidas == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "VOCÊ PERDEU");
            jlSegredo.setText("");
            jlRevela.setText("REVELADOR");
            jlResta.setText("");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jogue novamente.");
        }
        if (jlSegredo.getText().equals(jlRevela.getText())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você descobriu a palavra. Parabéns!");
            jlSegredo.setText("");
            jlRevela.setText("REVELADOR");
            jlResta.setText("");
        }
    }
    jtChute.setText("");
    jtChute.requestFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro está ocorrendo nesta linha provavelmente:

```
int vidas = Integer.parseInt(jlResta.getText());
```

supondo que esta seja o único uso do `parseXXX` no seu código. Pela mensagem, você está tentando converter uma string vazia em número.

Se este campo é de entrada de usuário, você precisa validar também se o valor recebido é convertível em um inteiro. Um jeito simples de validar isso é justamente capturar a exceção que esse método lança, a `NumberFormatException`

```
int vidas;

try{

vidas = Integer.parseInt(jlResta.getText());

} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
//aqui você faz algo quando o valor não for um número
}
```

Se esse campo não for uma entrada de usuário, você deve garantir que ele sempre tenha um valor numérico antes de fazer a conversão.

Pelo que pude perceber, trata-se de um campo de texto para exibir o número de tentativas restantes, se for essa a única finalidade, recomendo usar um `JLabel`, já que a finalidade, pelo que parece, é apenas mostrar ao player quantas tentativas ele ainda tem.

Comment: A finalidade era mostrar as tentativas restantes. Ou seja, o erro era referente ao JLabel mesmo. Não havia inserido nenhum número inicial. Deu certo com sua dica. Obrigado.

Comment: @DeiseBackes que bom que a resposta ajudou a solucionar. Se quiser, você pode aceitar a resposta clicando no V abaixo dos pontos, assim, você indica a outros com problema semelhante que a solução lhe foi útil :)